# Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':google_sign_in:debugCompileClasspath'

Tags: flutter, dart

App was working completely fine but suddenly it is invoking the following issue.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':google_sign_in:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':google_sign_in:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :google_sign_in_web.
     Required by:
         project :google_sign_in
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :google_sign_in_web:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have imported the latest google_sign_in package in pubspec.yaml but still facing the same build failed error. Any help please!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by running following command in flutter terminal:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

All of the packages were downloaded and re-installed again.